# Continuity of Potential across a boundary

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

The electric field across a boundary is discontinuous. Does this mean there is no field at the boundary? Can you explain if there is no electric field there, the work done across the boundary?

Comment: think of a straight slope  on a mountain, then there is a vertical Step and after it the slope ist steeper (or less steep) Is there no work going au over tis disconuiity?

Comment: what about the work between two points both on the vertical step?

Comment: Near duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500667/

Comment: If your field is truly discontinuous, then there is no meaning to "at the boundary".   But you can figure out what's going on by replacing the discontinuity (unphysical) with a very steep slope (an improvement).